# How to use ajaxdoc

Tags: javascript, comments, xml-comments

I am not able to figure it , How to use [ajaxdoc](http://ajaxdoc.codeplex.com/) for generating comments for my scripts.

I would appreciate, if you can provide a little tutorial about this or an example. Do I need to use this project dll.

Comment: I am afraid there is no dll in the download-able file. Also, have you experienced problems with the sample code on the homepage?

Comment: yes, when I run the default.aspx it has two textarea. But I dont know what to do with it.